# iOS 9 iphone keyboard issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview, appframework

i'm building an ios app that is made with [AppFramework Intel](http://app-framework-software.intel.com/) and Xcode.
The files (html, js, css, img) are inside the app and are loaded by UiWebView.
I have some forms that require the user include some values.
When the input fields are pressed for some reason the keyboard is bigger than the conventional:

Here is how the keyboard looks like and should be.

[image]
http://backstagedigital.com.br/stackoverflow/keyboard-issue.png


Any help is welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to apple documentation:

> **Configuring the Keyboard for Web Views**
>
> Although the UIWebView class does not support the UITextInputTraits protocol directly, you can configure some keyboard attributes for text input elements. For example, you can include autocorrect and autocapitalize attributes in the definition of an input element to specify the keyboard’s behaviors, as shown in the following example.

```
<input type="text" size="30" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="on">
```

> You can also control which type of keyboard is displayed when a user touches a text field in a web page. To display a telephone keypad, an email keyboard, or a URL keyboard, use the tel, email, or url keywords for the type attribute on an input element, respectively. To display a numeric keyboard, set the value of the pattern attribute to "[0-9]*" or "\d*".
>
> These keywords and the pattern attribute are part of HTML 5 and are available in iOS. The following list shows how to display each type of keyboard, including the standard keyboard.

```
Text: <input type="text"></input>
Telephone: <input type="tel"></input>
URL: <input type="url"></input>
Email: <input type="email"></input>
Zip code: <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*"></input>
```

You can find the complete article here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

Comment: Thanks! I figured out that uiwebview keyboard size is bigger than the conventional, but adding this attributes make the app better and more useful.